# How do I pass a prop as an argument in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I am new to Vue and I am making a component that changes it's class property based on the style prop given by the parent component. When I try to invoke a substitution Vue does nothing

Here is "Top.vue", the title prop is passed and the button renders it fine, however the href and style props don't

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import Button from './Button.vue'
</script>

<template>
<div class=flex>
<Button href="test" title="Home" alt="To home" style="top" />
</div>
</template>
```

Here is "Button.vue"

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps({
    href: String,
    title: String,
    alt: String,
    style: String
})
</script>

<template>
<a href="{{ href }}"><button class="{{ style }}">{{ title }}</button></a>
</template>
```

I want for Vue to resolve this to

```html
<a href="test"><button class="top">Home</button></a>
```

However it resolves to

```html
<a href="{{ href }}"><button class="{{ style }}">Home</button></a>
```

Notice how `{{ title }}` resolves properly but `{{ href }}` and `{{ style }}` do not

Comment: `style` and `class` are handled differently in vuejs, not sure what's happening with `href` - but the fact that your component is called `Button` may be something to do with these issue. Try calling your component something that isn't an existing element in HTML ... say ... `my-button` for example? (or `MyButton` if you're not into kebab case)

Comment: having said that, have you tried `<a :href="href"><button :class="style">.....` - though, `:class="style"` may still look odd, since the aforementioned handling of style/class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<button>` element name, `style` attribute, etc. are reserved words.  You should come up with custom names for your props and components rather than reuse standard HTML attribute/element names.

Regarding your prop troubles, review the documentation on how to [use props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#static-vs-dynamic-props).  Binding prop values to elements is done with `v-bind` or just `:` for short, e.g. `:href="test"`. The double curly braces `{{ }}` is for [text interpolation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#text-interpolation) and should be used *between* element tags when you're trying to display a value.

Try this code instead:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import StyledButton from './StyledButton.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <div class=flex>
    <StyledButton link="test" title="Home" altText="To home" classStyle="top" />
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps({
    link: String,
    title: String,
    altText: String,
    classStyle: String
})
</script>

<template>
  <a :href="link">
    <button :class="classStyle">{{ title }}</button>
  </a>
</template>
```